# iOS SDK address book issue

Tags: iphone

I'm getting my array filled by getting contact from contact.contactName.

is there any way i can get count of all the contact name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
  {
  NSLog(@"mny bebabasbd = %d",[self.contacts count]);
      return self.contacts.count;
  }

i figure out with this. thanks any way.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an array called `contacts` you can do like so

```
int contactCount = [contacts count];
```